# O que fazer quando um model tem N responsabilidades

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework-6, lógica

Meu sistema existe uma classe que atualmente é uma classe comum para várias situações, abaixo algum dos outros modelos para exemplificar

```
public class Servico
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public decimal? Valor {get;set;}
}
public class Coleta : Servico
{
    //dados da colheita
}
public class Faturamento
{
    public ICollection<Servico> Servicos {get;set;}
}
```

Então, esse Serviço poderá ser cadastrado como

```
var servico = new Servico("Coleta de sangue",5.00);
```

Serviço é um `model` comum, apenas para não haver repetição de registros e para o usuário escolher em um `select` o ou os serviços, sem a necessidade de ter que cadastrar novamente

Mas a Coleta também é um serviço, que pode ou não ser realizado na empresa, caso for realizado dentro da empresa, ele terá seu outros campos...

Mas como eu posso impedir de quando eu for fazendo várias coletas, minha Lista de registros de serviços não fique enorme? Ou seja, o `model` `Servico` é apenas uma referencia simples, já o `Coleta`, é um model mais completo, *que pode existir ações dentro dele*

**[Edit]**

Um exemplo em passo a passo do processo.

1. Cadastro do serviço (Coleta de sangue)
2. Referenciado em uma ordem de serviço
3. Se for feito na empresa, a TELA é própria, com outros campos, etc, representado pela classe Coleta
4. Ir para o faturamento como Serviço

O que eu estou fazendo, deixo em uma `constant` o nome do Serviço Coleta de Sangue, não deixo o usuário editar, e quando gero uma ordem de serviço, eu gero uma classe de `Coleta.cs` caso for feito na empresa (tem na `view` um `checkbox` falando se é feito lá ou por terceiros)

Também poderia ter dentro da classe `Coleta.cs`, um `ServicoId`, então selecionar ele, quando for fazer a Coleta, entretanto é chato e ruim para o usuário, já que é a Coleta de Sangue e não outro serviço, também, se ele tiver muitos serviços, é ruim pra ficar buscando.

Comment: Isto parece ser código do Entity Framework. Se você colocar as tags, posso tentar responder.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sim, também pode ser válida na modelagem do db mesmo, já editei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Entity Framework, para o caso de heranças, é criada a tabela com o nome da classe ancestral, com todos os campos das classes derivadas, e uma coluna a mais chamada de [*discriminator*](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx). O preenchimento desta coluna extra é feito pelo próprio *framework*.

Para tratar especificamente de um Serviço ou de uma Coleta, crie um `DbSet<>` para cada:

```
public DbSet<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
public DbSet<Coleta> Coletas { get; set; }
```

Se você extrair a sentença gerada a partir de qualquer `IQueryable<Coleta>`, verá que `select`s, `insert`s, `update`s e `delete`s referenciam `Servicos`, e não `Coletas`.

Agora, se você não quiser usar dois `DbSet<>`, não tem problema: o operador `OfType<>` resolve qual classe você está querendo selecionar:

```
var coletasDeServicos = db.Servicos.OfType<Coleta>().Where(...).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso vai depender da sua **regra de negócios**.

Quando você vai adicionar **Coletas** a sua lista de serviços você pode realizar este tratamento.

Por exemplo, só pode ter 10 coletas na lista, então você trata o método que usa para adicionar. Ao adicionar verifica se há muitas coletas e toma a decisão desejada (pode ser excluir as coletas mais velhas ou parar de incluir).

Agora se você trabalha no banco de dados, pode ir adicionando, mas ao consultar pode consultar apenas uma determinada quantidade. Procedimento conhecido por **paginação**.

Comment: Não é bem paginação, a dúvida ta mais para modelagem e regra de negócio...